# ¿Cómo hacer para recibir el nombre del producto y enviarlo por un alert?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una página en la cual muestro un grid con productos: cada box esta hecho a mano, y necesito crear un botón con una función que cuente el botón presionado y el nombre de producto que tiene. Tengo una función `recibir()`, la cual guardaría el nombre del producto y lo enviaría en un `alert()` y una llamada `contar()` la cual contaría qué botón se apretó. Cada botón tiene su id.

Inserto parte del código

```
<div class="prod1">
    <h1>Xiaomi 11 </h1>
    <br>
    <img src="https://www.pcfactory.cl/public/foto/43956/1_100.jpg?t=1653944627754">
    <p>$264.990<br>Precio<br> Oferta <br> Efectivo</p>
    <br>
    <button id="bt1" class="btn-comprar"><a href="compra.html">Comprar</a></button>
</div>


<div class="prod2">
    <h1>Xiaomi 12 </h1>
    <br>
    <img src="https://www.pcfactory.cl/public/foto/43956/1_100.jpg?t=1653944627754">
    <p>$264.990<br>Precio<br> Oferta <br> Efectivo</p>
    <br>
    <button id="bt2" class="btn-comprar"><a href="compra.html">Comprar</a></button>
</div>


<div class="prod3"> 
    <h1>Xiaomi 13 </h1>
    <br>
    <img src="https://www.pcfactory.cl/public/foto/43956/1_100.jpg?t=1653944627754">
    <p>$264.990<br>Precio<br> Oferta <br> Efectivo</p>
    <br>
    <button id="bt3" class="btn-comprar"><a href="compra.html">Comprar</a></button>
</div>
```

Mi duda es cómo hacer para recibir el nombre del producto y enviarlo por un alert, iba a usar un document.getbyid pero ¿tendría que crear uno por cada id?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes pasarle a cada botón la función `onclick` y la palabra reservada `this` como argumento para identificar facilmente el botón clickado.

`onclick="obtenerId(this)"`

Luego en `JS` recibes el parámetro y accedes al atributo `id` para mostrarlo en consola, en un `alert` o para usarlo como desees.

```js
function obtenerId(boton){
  let idBoton = boton.id;
  alert(idBoton);
}
```

```html
<div class="prod1">
  <h1>Xiaomi 11 </h1>
  <br>
  <img src="https://www.pcfactory.cl/public/foto/43956/1_100.jpg?t=1653944627754">
  <p>$264.990<br>Precio<br> Oferta <br> Efectivo</p>
  <br>
  <button id="bt1" class="btn-comprar" onclick="obtenerId(this)"><a href="#">Comprar</a></button>
</div>
<div class="prod2">
  <h1>Xiaomi 12 </h1>
  <br>
  <img src="https://www.pcfactory.cl/public/foto/43956/1_100.jpg?t=1653944627754">
  <p>$264.990<br>Precio<br> Oferta <br> Efectivo</p>
  <br>
  <button id="bt2" class="btn-comprar" onclick="obtenerId(this)"><a href="#">Comprar</a></button>
</div>
<div class="prod3">
  <h1>Xiaomi 13 </h1>
  <br>
  <img src="https://www.pcfactory.cl/public/foto/43956/1_100.jpg?t=1653944627754">
  <p>$264.990<br>Precio<br> Oferta <br> Efectivo</p>
  <br>
  <button id="bt3" class="btn-comprar" onclick="obtenerId(this)"><a href="#">Comprar</a></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu comentario, me ayudaste caleta :D